# Is there a call back when month view was changed in FullCalendar 5?

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I want to be able to get current month and year = calendar title.

The calendar is very simple, just monthly view. I found there used to be few callbacks in previous versions but I cannot find any in current (V5.x) version.

The only thing I see how to solve this is to create custom buttons for month change.

```
document.getElementById('my-prev-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  calendar.prev();
  // and here I can get the title
});
```

Is there any native way how to get current title after user changes a month?

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/mdektyzu/7/).

[image]

Comment: Why would you need to get the month title? And what callbacks in previous versions are you thinking of?

Comment: I think it was https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/viewRender, see that we are not able to change the version to V5. I want to make it easier for user to see what data range is going to be processed so I take the title after change a display it somewhere else.

Comment: I see. The only way I can think of is to set up a fake event feed using https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function and within the callback instead of making an AJAX request or returning any events, you simply extract the month from the start date provided. Obviously it won't be the exact title text as displayed, but you can easily format it the same way fullCalendar does. Event feeds are really the only thing which detect date range changes in v5.

Comment: I solved it by using MutationObserver ` var target = document.getElementsByClassName('fc-toolbar-title')[0]`. After I posted this question. I still wonder if there is a FullCalendar native way.

Comment: There isn't, according to the documentation. You can always make a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features), and even offer to contribute the code yourself, if you like. You should post that mutation observer code as an Answer though, if you found that was a good workaround.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround - I still prefer native solution - I used [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

```
var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
  allDaySlot : false,
  slotMinTime : "06:00:00",
  slotMaxTime : "20:00:00",
  firstDay : 2,
  selectable: true,
  select: function(info) {
    console.log('selected ' + info.startStr + ' to ' + info.endStr);

  }
})
   
calendar.render()
   
var target = document.getElementsByClassName('fc-toolbar-title')[0]
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  console.log(target.innerText);   
  console.log("comming from obeserver")
});
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true, subtree: true };
observer.observe(target, config);
```

Working [jsFiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/nex3t0ky/13/)